# How to provide java program with external files when executing the run command in console?

Tags: java, execution

So it might seem like a trivial question, but I cannot find any information out there that answers my question. Nonetheless, it is a very general coding question.

Suppose you have a java program that reads a file and creates a data structure based on the information provided by the file. So you do:

```
javac javaprogram.java
java javaprogram
```

Easy enough, but what I want to do here is to provide the program with a file specified in the command line, like this:

```
javac javaprogram.java
java javaprogram -file
```

What code do I have to write to conclude this very concern? 
Thanks.

Comment: Everything you pass on the command line you'll see in the `String[] args` parameter of your `main` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the best *command-line* utility libraries for *Java* out there is [*JCommander*](http://jcommander.org/).

A trivial implementation based on your thread description would be:

```java
public class javaprogram {

    @Parameter(names={"-file"})
    String filePath;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // instantiate your main class
        javaprogram program = new javaprogram();

        // intialize JCommander and parse input arguments
        JCommander.newBuilder().addObject(program).build().parse(args);
        
        // use your file path which is now accessible through the 'filePath' field
    }

}
```

You should make sure that the library *jar* is available under your classpath when compiling the *javaprogram.java* class file.

Otherwise, in case you don't need an utility around you program argument, you may keep the program entry simple enough reading the file path as a raw program argument:

```java
public class javaprogram {

    private static final String FILE_SWITCH = "-file";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if ((args.length == 2) && (FILE_SWITCH.equals(args[0]))) {
            final String filePath = args[1];
            // use your file path which is now accessible through the 'filePath' local variable
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A newer/modern alternative to JCommander that may be of interest is [picocli](https://github.com/remkop/picocli).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is using -D, so if you have some file, you could call

```
java -Dmy.file=file.txt javaprogram
```

And inside you program you could read it with `System.getProperty("my.file")`.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filename = System.getProperty("my.file");
        if (filename == null) {
            System.exit(-1); // Or wharever you want
        }

        // Read and process your file
    }
}
```

Or you could use third a party tool like [picocli](https://picocli.info)

```
import java.io.File;
import picocli.CommandLine;
import picocli.CommandLine.Command;
import picocli.CommandLine.Option;

@Command(name = "Sample", header = "%n@|green Sample demo|@")
public class Sample implements Runnable {

    @Option(names = {"-f", "--file"}, required = true, description = "Filename")
    private File file;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("Loading %s%n", file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CommandLine.run(new Sample(), System.err, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you provide the actual file name and make the call to run the command line app?
I get an error that there is no `Sample()` class available.

Comment: @Arefe sorry for the delay in the response, but I was very busy at the beginning of the year.

This [gists](https://gist.github.com/jadler/427a3fc2ebcee373eaf084a9cda94289) if fully functional, I get no error, let me know if something goes wrong.

Comment: This was solved at that time, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass file path as argument in two ways:

1)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("File path plz");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("File path: " + args[0]);
    }

}
```

2) Use [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Let's go step by step. First you need to pass the file path to your program.
Lets say you execute your program like this:

```
java javaprogram /foo/bar/file.txt
```

Strings that come after "javaprogram" will be passed as arguments to your program. This is the reason behind the syntax of the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 //args is the array that would store all the values passed when executing your program
 String filePath = args[0]; //filePath will contain /foo/bar/file.txt
}
```

Now that you were able to get a the file path and name from the command-line, you need to open and read your file.

Take a look at File class and FileInputStream class.
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-in-java-fileinputstream/

That should get you started.

Good luck!